# Symfony Error: Call to a member function format() on string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I know there has been a few post in stackoverflow around my question, but none of the responses seem to be working for me, and this is why I'm posting here.

I have a class with created_at and updated_at, both are expecting a datetime value

In my setter I have:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now');
$stimestamp = $date->format('M-d-Y H:i:s');
$this->setUpdatedAt($stimestamp);
```

Same error occurs when I use the following

```
 $this->setUpdatedAt(strtotime($stimestamp));
```

I get the following error:
Error: Call to a member function format() on string

My Oracle database is expecting the datetime as following 'DD-MON-YYYY' but doctrine is generating the query as 'Y-d-M' Which I think is the UNIX format.

How can I resolve that I can send the proper datetime value and format?

Comment: That should work correctly. What do you get when you `var_dump($date);`?

Comment: dump is showing the proper values, but as soon I call $this->setUpdatedAt(strtotime($stimestamp)) is when I get the error

Comment: You wrote that created_at and updated_at expecting datetime value, but DateTime::format returns a string, so how the setUpdatedAt() method implementation looks like?

Comment: the format of the date is string and not datetime type thus you are getting the error

Comment: But I get the same error even using strtotime($stimestamp) which returns a date. So how can I send current datetime in the format is Oracle expecting it?

Comment: Implementation of setters looks like this:  public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

Comment: The Doctrine itself is responsible for converting DateTime to proper SQL db type.

Comment: @Jan Rydrych Is not happening because if I send the date only, like new \Datetime('now') I get an error of ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Doctrine expects `DateTime` instances. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#date

Comment: @Jan Rydrych how do I check that? php.ini? symfony framework?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this if it can solve the issue (Of course don't forget to alter the format strings according to your locale).

```
   $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
   $dbh = $em->getConnection();
   $sth = $dbh->prepare("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIME_FORMAT = 'HH24:MI:SS' NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'");
   $sth->execute();
```

Comment: I think we are in the right track here, in my case the controller looks like this: $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); $em->persist($object);
$em->flush(); Some of your methods are not available, like getConnection and prepare

Comment: Another option would be to create custom mapping type and then use it instead of standard Doctrine datetime. Check this http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in another post here on Stackoverflow, unfortunately I lost the link. Jan Rydrych answer was in the right path, but I didn't wanted to apply  his solution on a controller class, instead I wanted to make it global.

In symfony, under services I added the following:

app/config.services.yml

```
oci8.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit
        arguments:
            - { NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT: "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM" }
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }
```

The above solved the problem.

Thank you all for the help.